# Chrome reload page after history.back

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, reload

Thats makes me crazy.
I am calling details page from primary page,  using, javascript - `window.open("4prod.html?pkd="+idd,'_self', false);`  that open in the same window page with product details. When this details page has been opened there is a button "back", again in javascript -`onclick="history.go(-1); return false;`.

In FF works great, it means, that on "back" button from details page, the primary page appears with state as I left it, but in Chrome and IE "back" button reload primary page and all entries (inputs, color changes etc. which users have made) have gone and new - refreshed page is displayed.
How I can avoid reloading in Chrome nad IE just call of cached primary page ?

Comment: Mybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307363/google-chrome-refreshing-without-been-asked-for-it

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8881088/2231440) says it's impossible without cookies if the URL changes. Is it possible to just have the form in one `<div>`, then hide it (and show the details in another `<div>`), then when the back button is clicked, just reverse this? If anything, (once the page has loaded the JS) the execution would be faster.